# How to Transfer a JSON value from a REST POST Response to a REST Get Request in SOAPUI

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I have a REST service which I am testing with SoapUI. The first step in my TestSuite returns the following Response (Json):

```
{   
  "mtMessageId": 52003685,   
  "status":    
  {
     "value": 0,
     "code": "OK",
     "text": "Text message submitted"   
  },   
  "custMessageId": 123,   
  "custMessageRef": null
}
```

I want to 'Transfer' the value from the mtMessageId into the HTTP Get Request in the next step.

The request is formatted like "/SMS/{id}"

How do I transfer the value into the Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to set the resource of your `get` method in your request with a property for example using `/SMS/${#TestCase#id}` in order to retrieve it from the first request.

[image]

Then add a `groovy script` testStep between your requests. An use the follow code to get the `id` from the json response of the first request and set as a property for the second request.

```
import groovy.json.*

// get the response from the first request using its name
def response = context.expand('${Request 1#Response}')
// parse it
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info json.mtMessageId
// get the json value an set it as property in testCase
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("id",json.mtMessageId.toString())
```

Note that you can use property transfer testStep to get the value from your request and set it as a property, however since SOAPUI converts all to xml I prefer to use a `groovy script` to work json.

Hope it helps,